# Indexing array of strings column type in PostgreSQL

Tags: arrays, database, postgresql

Is it possible to create an index on a column with type of **text array**. Tried using **GIN** indexes, but queries do not seem to be using those indexes.

```
-- Example:
CREATE TABLE users (
   name VARCHAR(100),
   groups TEXT[],
);

-- Query: 
SELECT name FROM users WHERE ANY(groups) = 'Engineering';
```

Also what is the best way to perform `GROUP BY` on `groups` column efficiently so that it can give `groups` and count.

Comment: What is preventing you from normalization?

Comment: Actual table has got multiple multi-valued columns. Db is relatively normalized expect for these columns where I wanted to avoid excessive joins as it is slowing down the performance. The 'User' table I used is just an example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A gin index can be used:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
 name VARCHAR(100),
 groups text[]
);

CREATE INDEX idx_users ON users USING GIN(groups);

-- disable sequential scan in this test:
SET enable_seqscan TO off;

EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT name FROM users WHERE  groups @> (ARRAY['Engineering']);
```

Result:

```
"Bitmap Heap Scan on users  (cost=4.26..8.27 rows=1 width=218) (actual time=0.021..0.021 rows=0 loops=1)"
"  Recheck Cond: (groups @> '{Engineering}'::text[])"
"  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_users  (cost=0.00..4.26 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.016..0.016 rows=0 loops=1)"
"        Index Cond: (groups @> '{Engineering}'::text[])"
"Total runtime: 0.074 ms"
```

Using aggregate functions on an array, that will be another problem. The function [unnest](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-array.html)() might help.

Why don't you normalize your data? That will fix all problems, including many problems you didn't encouter yet.

Comment: I think I didn't use ARRAY['Engineering'] in the query and as a result GIN index never got used. Regarding normalization, actual table and use case is different from what I have mentioned.  Actual table do have multiple columns which are multivalued represented using array of strings. I was trying to avoid multiple joins as the expected number of records per table is of the order of millions.

Comment: I think the operator @> makes all the difference, it looks like ANY() can't use the index.

Comment: Specifically when you expect large intermediate and/or result tables you should make your data as accessible to the DBMS as you can. Normalization allows it to work with a reference in several cases where otherwise you'd work with values.

Comment: Using explain I see no difference between operator @> en any(), both give identically:
explain select count(*) from kwetsbaar.kwo where bijztype @> (array['WON'])::varchar[];
Finalize Aggregate  (cost=505166.56..505166.57 rows=1 width=8)
   ->  Gather  (cost=505166.14..505166.55 rows=4 width=8)
         Workers Planned: 4
         ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=504166.14..504166.15 rows=1 width=8)
               ->  Parallel Seq Scan on kwo  (cost=0.00..500662.60 rows=1401414 width=0)
                     Filter: (bijztype @> '{WON}'::character varying[])
with GIN index, 8 million rows.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to handle this would be to normalize your model. The following will probably contain errors as I didn't try it, but the idea should be clear:

```
CREATE TABLE users (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(100) UNIQUE);
CREATE TABLE groups (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(100) UNIQUE);
CREATE TABLE user_group (
    user INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES users,
    group INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES groups);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX user_group_unique ON user_group (user, group);

SELECT users.name
    FROM user_group
    INNER JOIN users ON user_group.user = users.id
    INNER JOIN groups ON user_group.group = groups.id
    WHERE groups.name = 'Engineering';
```

The resulting execution plan should be fairly efficient already; you can optimize still by indexing ON user_group(group), which allows an index_scan rather than a sequential_scan to find the members of a particular group.

Comment: I wanted to avoid normalization for this particular use case. That is the reason why I was forced to use array of strings data type.

Answer (score 0):

There is array_to_tsvector() function as of PostgreSQL 9.6 now.

https://pgpedia.info/a/array_to_tsvector.html

So maybe quite efficient is to create tsvectors and use gin index on them.